# Change numeric format in R

Tags: r, import-from-csv

How can I change the value `20,000` to `20000` in **R**? In my case, I have a CSV file where column A is a value with format `xx,xxx` and column B is a group name.

So

```
data[,1]
[1] 203,472.40 226,433.70 ...
100 Levels: 101,051.40 103,662.70 ...
```

The numerical value is a factor instead of numeric.

I to convert `data[,1]` to

```
[1] 203472.40 226433.70 ...
```

I've tried `as.numeric`, but this doesn't work with factors.

Comment: as.numeric may do what you wish?

Comment: what u exact want to do?
amount type
20000  abc

Comment: when reading the data, you can set `dec=","`, which will read data as numeric values (comma will separate decimals) and then you can multiple them by `1000` to get the correct values

Comment: cant use as.numeric as the data is in level. @Zbynek where i should put dec=","? Thanks

Comment: `read.csv('path.to.file', dec=',')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, you need to:

1. Convert the factor to character - `as.character`
2. Remove the comma - `gsub`
3. Convert to numeric - `as.numeric`

So

```
x = factor(c("203,472.40","226,433.70"))
as.numeric(gsub(",", "", as.character(x)))
```

Of course, you should try and fix the problem (if possible) up-stream, i.e. using `dec` in `read.csv`

Comment: Thanks for your help it do exactly what i need. <br/>
while i tried data<-read.csv("rev3.csv","dec=","). It do not work. Maybe it is because i got two attributes that another one besides value is a character "Name".